# How can I determine angular velocity from a fixed heading while dealing with the wrap around

Tags: math, lua, trigonometry, angle

I am trying to determine angular velocity in degrees per second of an object.

I have only the heading of that object in degrees updated every 1/60th of a second (with 0 being North and 90 being East)

The specific issue I have is one of handling the wrap around when the object goes from say 355 degrees to 5 degrees passing over 0/360.

I'm currently thinking that perhaps I can average readings over time, excluding the outliers however that will add unnecessary lag to the system and reduce accuracy over that region.

Simple example code where degreesIn is the source and degreesPerSecondOut is the result

```
degreesPerSecondOut = (degreesIn or 0 - degreesInOld) * 60
degreesInOld = degreesIn
```

Expected results include a smooth and accurate transition whilst passing over 0 degrees

---

Additional Thought: The object I am calculating the angular velocity of should never exceed 1 revolution per second (or even per 1/60th of a second). Im not sure why but I feel this is useful.

Comment: Can you give us an idea on what can influence the angular velocity, does it decelerate over time. As well as how many objects you are predicting, an idea that comes to mind is to have the object call out every time it rotates 1 degree, then find the time it took from the last callout.

Comment: Angular velocity is dependant on external factors not controlled by this system, I only need to speed of this one object and I already get an update every 1/60th of a second (every tick)

Comment: can you grab the object's properties, such as its rotation? And how fast are you expecting for it to rotate (this will play a major role in lag)

Comment: I have the objects current orientation (rotation) in degrees relative to north updated at 60hz.

The problem is purely to do with the wrap around. Figuring out angular velocity outside of that is no issue

Comment: I would keep doing what you were doing before, just decrease the sample rate. You might be able to further reduce lag by grabbing measurements in bursts, then averaging: grab 3 measurements 2 ticks apart (each tick is around 16ms) every 11 ticks (total of 15 ticks, measure-2-measure-2-measure-11-repeat) This way you can get 4 semi-accurate samples per second

Comment: Oh, just saw your edited comment, realizing that using a sine function might be quite useful here, since sine waves do "wrap-around" automatically

Comment: Why do you need the `or 0`?

Comment: @kabanus that is not essential actually. Its purely there in the event that the variable isn't initialized.

Comment: @IoCalisto What Im doing before has the angular rate fluctuate wildly when passing across 0. I have no issue with the tick rate really, just the wrap around. I think Im figuring it out though based on the edit I made. 

I think I just have to use that assumption (that the rate will never exceed 360 per tick) which makes sense as thats the most accurate I could get anyways.

Comment: You could throw out measurements that seem off, since by the time the rotation gets to the wrap-around point, you already have an average, you could then compare the perceived change in velocity (a strong negative value) to the average. Another redundancy you could put in place to fight against false-positives for this throw away system, would have a temp array store how many values were discarded in a row, and above a threshold, it could re-adjust to accept new values.

Comment: So you have 6 ticks per degree max?

Comment: @IoCalisto I have a maximum of <360 degrees per tick, but practically the object never really goes above a handful.

I Think I've probably solved the problem however. Im sure there is a more ideal solution, but I will post the one I think I have.

Comment: Another idea I'll throw out there for documentation, is to split the rotational possibilities into two sets of 180; 0 being north and both sides increasing towards 180 at south, you won't be able to detect the direction of rotation, but you can get the velocity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My take:

```
function velocity(ain,aout)
    ipersec = 60
    raw = aout - ain
    turn = math.min((-math.abs(raw))%360,math.abs(raw)%360)
    direction = math.abs(raw)/raw
    return direction*turn*ipersec
end
print(velocity(5,355),velocity(355,5),velocity(20,40),velocity(40,20))
--[[600    -600    1200    -1200--]]
```

My take - you have three components:

1. Wrap around, simply handled with a `%360`. `math.mod` will work for 5.0.
2. Even with wrap around, there are two ways you could have turned - we always want the minimal turn.
3. A sign portion which indicates direction.

Once you handle the wrap around, you realize that 355->5 or backward is no different then 10->20 - you could have taken 10 degrees, or 350, but we assume the shortest.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a solution to my answer. Unfortunately I dont think it is necessarily the best solution, as with this solution only up to a maximum of ~180 degrees per tick (10800 degrees per second/1800RPM)  but I believe it solves my problem and is accurate enough for my application.

Here it is:

"angularVelocity" is the velocity calculated

"rotationInDegrees" is the input rotation/heading

"rotationInDegreesOld" is the previous rotation/heading

```
if (rotationInDegrees - rotationInDegreesOld > 180) then
    angularVelocity = rotationInDegrees - rotationInDegreesOld - 360 * 60
elseif (inputRotation - inputRotationOld < 180) then
    angularVelocity = rotationInDegrees- rotationInDegreesOld + 360 * 60
else
    angularVelocity= rotationInDegrees - rotationInDegreesOld * 60
end
```

To explain what is happening, when the rate is so high that I assume it has wrapped around (like when you go from 355 degrees to 5 degrees where the measurement that tick would be -350 * 60 degrees per second) 360 is added to it making it the more reasonable option of 10 degrees.

The same applies in the other direction but with subtracting 360 rather than adding.